# Python, Segmentation fault

Tags: python, binary

I am reading binary files in python 2.7.3 in this way:

```
import os, struct
from numpy import *

win_span = 8
coinc_window = zeros(2)
event = asarray((False, False, False, False))
Statistics = zeros(5)

with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(8)
    while byte != "":
        time_bin = struct.unpack("<Q", byte)[0]
        byte = f.read(2)
        channel_tag = struct.unpack("<H", byte)[0]
        if time_bin > coinc_window[1] + win_span:
            Statistics[4] += event[0]*event[2]
            event = asarray((False, False, False, False))
            coinc_window = coinc_window[::-1]
            coinc_window[1] = time_bin
        event[channel_tag-1] = True
        Statistics[channel_tag-1] += 1
        byte = f.read(8)    
print "Fin"
```

It works fine for small binary files (~2MB), but when I run it for binary files over size ~6MB, it actually finishes the running but also gives this error: "Segmentation fault".
I don't know what it is going wrong?

Comment: Does the segfault still occur when you comment out the `doing other stuff` part? In other words, does it occur is *all you do* is read and unpack?

Comment: Works for me (ie no seg fault) (once I've added `import struct`) on an 8MB file made from `/dev/urandom`. **shrug** I blame the 'other stuff'

Comment: enable [`faulthandler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/) and show the traceback.

Comment: Actually by commenting out `doing other stuff`, I don't get segmentation fault anymore. I should refine that part, but nevertheless the code runs completely and gives the error too. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should include that "other stuff", so that we can tell you what's actually wrong with your code.

Comment: I've put the whole code. The way it is written, is running very slowly. I also appreciate any ideas for refining the algorithm.

Comment: I've replaced all of `numpy.ndarray`s with `list`s and the problem is gone away, and it runs much faster. Thanks guys.